# Header background only covers 80% width on mobile

Tags: html, css

On a site I'm designing I have a header that stretches 100% of the page width and in all browsers it looks perfect but when I check mobile browsers it will only stretch about 80% of the screen while the rest of the content will go full width.

```
#header-bg{
height: 150px;
background-color: #33363b;
border-top: 11px solid #25272a;
width: 100%;
}
```

The site is http://hearthable.com and here is a image of it from an iPhone, the same thing happens on android too. You can see in the image below the dark blue background in the header and footer don't go the full width.

[image]

Comment: This hasnt to do with the image, but with the body. I've encountered this problem a while ago, too bad I cant think of that it was. Try using firebug to see if one of the elements is bigger than it should be

Comment: Add `body {
min-width: 1190px;
}
`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you put width:100%; which are relative to the window size. Your site is not responsive designed, but to solve your problem fast

```
body{
     min-width:1180px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

setting minimum width as others suggested is not the best option, as different devices have different screen widths, and it also changes according to screen rotation.

however, adding `display:inline-block;` in both `header-bg` and `footer` will fix it.

EDIT:

oh yes, and `width:100%` in both `footer` and `footer-inner`